# How to get Latitude and Longitude value from kataklisma / android-google-places Library

Tags: android, json, parsing, google-places-api

Well I Have implemented  [kataklisma / android-google-places library](https://github.com/kataklisma/android-google-places)
 for parsing the Google places API data, but I cant find the Following methods

```
place.getLatitude();
place.getLongitude();
```

I m getting all these

```
place.getName()
place.getFormattedAddress()
place.getIcon()
place.getId()
place.getReference()
place.getVicinity()
```

via following code successfully

```
if (result.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.OK) {

        List<Place> placesList = (List<Place>) result.getResults();
        for (Place place : placesList) {

            StaticParsedData.PLACE_NAMEs.add(place.getName());
            StaticParsedData.PLACE_FORMATED_ADDRESSEs.add(place
                    .getFormattedAddress());
            StaticParsedData.PLACE_ICONs.add(place.getIcon());
            StaticParsedData.PLACE_IDs.add(place.getId());
            StaticParsedData.PLACE_REFRENCEs.add(place.getReference());
            StaticParsedData.PLACE_VISINITIEs.add(place.getVicinity());

        }
```

but i need to get the Latitude and Longitude of the places also,But I cant find any method to get latitude and Longitude values. I don't think that following methods are available in this library.

```
place.Latitude();
place.Longitude();
```

May be I am doing wrong. can any body guide me regarding this. how to get Latitude and Longitude of any place via this library

Also here is an image of the library showing the `packages` hierarchy and its `libs`

[image]

*Or is there any other Robust library for parsing the data of Google Places API*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Yes I was doing wrong. To get latitude and longitude of the place we have to extract it from Geometry object like this.

First you have to get Object of the Geometry like this

```
if (result.getStatusCode() == StatusCode.OK) {

    List<Place> placesList = (List<Place>) result.getResults();
    for (Place place : placesList) {


        StaticParsedData.PLACE_GEOMETERIEs.add(place.getGeometery());

    }
```

and then extract the individual latitude and longitude of any place like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < StaticParsedData.PLACE_NAMEs.size(); i++) {

                                    Geometry geometry = StaticParsedData.PLACE_GEOMETERIEs
                                            .get(i);
                                    com.a2plab.googleplaces.models.Place.Location location = geometry.location;
                                    Double lat = location.lat;
                                    Double lng = location.lng;

                                    MarkerOptions placesIndicater = new MarkerOptions()
                                            .icon(placeMarkerIcon)
                                            .title(StaticParsedData.PLACE_NAMEs
                                                    .get(i))
                                            .snippet(
                                                    StaticParsedData.PLACE_VISINITIEs
                                                            .get(i))
                                            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                                    placeMarker = map
                                            .addMarker(placesIndicater);
                                    placeMarkerRef.add(placeMarker);

                                }
```